# I cant insert cell in my table using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i am creating this app and then i use javascript so that whatever i input in the boxes i could see it in my DETAILS HISTORY. and i did insert cells and stuff but when i run it i could see my table data getting inserted but only a few seconds then it will disappear i dont know why i hope you cn help me <3. here below is my codes

```js
let enter = document.getElementById("btn");
enter.addEventListener("click", displayFunction);
let row = 1;
function displayFunction() {
  let detail = document.getElementById("detail-input").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount-input").value;

  if (!detail || !amount) {
    alert("Please Fill in the Boxes");
    return;
  }

  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let newRow = table.insertRow(row);

  let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = detail;
  cell2.innerHTML = amount;
  row++;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.685);
}

.form-container {
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    55deg,
    rgb(71, 126, 247),
    rgba(53, 52, 52, 0.295)
  );
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(37, 37, 49);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(58, 57, 57);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #333;
  position: relative;
}

.form-container h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.form-container h3 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.form-container h3::before {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}

.form-container h3::after {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 32, 32);
}

.detail {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.amount {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 28%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms ease-out;
}

#btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.history {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.label-1 {
  color: green;
}

.label-2 {
  color: red;
}

.label-3 {
  color: rgb(24, 166, 223);
}

.details-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(
    55deg,
    rgb(71, 126, 247),
    rgba(53, 52, 52, 0.295)
  );
}

.details-container h1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

#myTable,
td,
th {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

td {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Expenses Tracker App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-container">
        <h1>EXPENSES TRACKER APP</h1>
        <h3>New Entry</h3>
        <form id="form">
          <div class="detail">
            <div class="col-1">
              <label>Details</label>
              <input type="text" id="detail-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amount">
            <div class="col-1">
              <label>Amount</label>
              <input type="number" id="amount-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button id="btn">Enter</button>
        </form>

        <div class="history">
          <div class="col-2 col-ie">
            <p class="label-1">INFLOW</p>
            <p id="inflow">$0.00</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p class="label-2">OUTFLOW</p>
            <p id="outflow">$0.00</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p class="label-3">BALANCE</p>
            <p id="balance">$0.00</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="details-container">
        <h1>DETAILS HISTORY</h1>
        <table id="myTable">
          <tr>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change button to `<button type="button"` you are submitting the form

Comment: When you submit a form, the default behaviour is to reload the page. Silly behaviour if you ask me. You have to use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent that

Comment: ohmy god you know what after i posted this problem thats exactly what i thought and then i saw your comments its all true thank youuuuu so much !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are submitting the form - you can change the button to type="button" OR
2. Don't use a submit button click to perform code, instead use the submit event and preventDefault()

---

```
let enter = document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", displayFunction);

function displayFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); <<<
```

```js
let enter = document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", displayFunction);
let row = 1;

function displayFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let detail = document.getElementById("detail-input").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount-input").value;

  if (!detail || !amount) {
    alert("Please Fill in the Boxes");
    return;
  }

  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let newRow = table.insertRow(row);

  let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = detail;
  cell2.innerHTML = amount;
  row++;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.685);
}

.form-container {
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient( 55deg, rgb(71, 126, 247), rgba(53, 52, 52, 0.295));
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(37, 37, 49);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(58, 57, 57);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #333;
  position: relative;
}

.form-container h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.form-container h3 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.form-container h3::before {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}

.form-container h3::after {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 32, 32);
}

.detail {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.amount {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 28%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms ease-out;
}

#btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.history {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.label-1 {
  color: green;
}

.label-2 {
  color: red;
}

.label-3 {
  color: rgb(24, 166, 223);
}

.details-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient( 55deg, rgb(71, 126, 247), rgba(53, 52, 52, 0.295));
}

.details-container h1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

#myTable,
td,
th {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

td {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-container">
    <h1>EXPENSES TRACKER APP</h1>
    <h3>New Entry</h3>
    <form id="form">
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="col-1">
          <label>Details</label>
          <input type="text" id="detail-input" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="amount">
        <div class="col-1">
          <label>Amount</label>
          <input type="number" id="amount-input" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="btn">Enter</button>
    </form>

    <div class="history">
      <div class="col-2 col-ie">
        <p class="label-1">INFLOW</p>
        <p id="inflow">$0.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <p class="label-2">OUTFLOW</p>
        <p id="outflow">$0.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <p class="label-3">BALANCE</p>
        <p id="balance">$0.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="details-container">
    <h1>DETAILS HISTORY</h1>
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let enter = document.getElementById("btn");
enter.addEventListener("click", displayFunction);
let row = 1;
function displayFunction() {
  let detail = document.getElementById("detail-input").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount-input").value;

  if (!detail || !amount) {
    alert("Please Fill in the Boxes");
    return;
  }

  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  console.log(table)
  let newRow = table.insertRow(row);

  let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  console.log(newRow);
  let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = detail;
  cell2.innerHTML = amount;
  row++;
  return;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.685);
}

.form-container {
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    55deg,
    rgb(71, 126, 247),
    rgba(53, 52, 52, 0.295)
  );
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(37, 37, 49);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(58, 57, 57);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #333;
  position: relative;
}

.form-container h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.form-container h3 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.form-container h3::before {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}

.form-container h3::after {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(41, 32, 32);
}

.detail {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.amount {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 28%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms ease-out;
}

#btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.history {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.label-1 {
  color: green;
}

.label-2 {
  color: red;
}

.label-3 {
  color: rgb(24, 166, 223);
}

.details-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(
    55deg,
    rgb(71, 126, 247),
    rgba(53, 52, 52, 0.295)
  );
}

.details-container h1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

#myTable,
td,
th {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

td {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Expenses Tracker App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-container">
        <h1>EXPENSES TRACKER APP</h1>
        <h3>New Entry</h3>
        <div id="form">
          <div class="detail">
            <div class="col-1">
              <label>Details</label>
              <input type="text" id="detail-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amount">
            <div class="col-1">
              <label>Amount</label>
              <input type="number" id="amount-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
<button id="btn">Enter</button>
        <div class="history">
          <div class="col-2 col-ie">
            <p class="label-1">INFLOW</p>
            <p id="inflow">$0.00</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p class="label-2">OUTFLOW</p>
            <p id="outflow">$0.00</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p class="label-3">BALANCE</p>
            <p id="balance">$0.00</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="details-container">
        <h1>DETAILS HISTORY</h1>
        <table id="myTable">
          <tr>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thats correct its because you use form here is result after replacing with div.
[https://jsfiddle.net/vishalpatil550/5xmu081o/7/][1]

Comment: agreed but if you are not submitting anything  then we don't need a form.